# Запуск Web-приложения на Flask с флешки

Tags: python, веб-сервер, flask

Здравствуйте, появилась необходимость быстро развернуть веб-приложение, написанное на Python и Flask на компьютере без самого интерпретатора Python, причем без всяких установок. В качестве БД используется MySQL.

Если бы приложение было написано на PHP, проблем бы вообще не было: ставим Denwer на флэшку, несем куда надо и запускаем. Но, как я понял для Python таких дистрибутивов нет.

В каталоге приложения лежит папка с виртуальным окружением Python, там же, как я понял, и сам интерпретатор и используемые библиотеки. Вопрос: если я просто на другом компе запущу `python.exe` из папки виртуального окружения, он заработает?(сам питон 32-битный, кроссплатформеность не нужна, Wind'ы хватит)

Если получится, как быть с MySQL, я вот еще читал, что XAMPP(или тот же Denwer) тоже можно запускать с флэшки, без установки и в него входит MySQL.

Короче, в ту ли я сторону копаю, и возможно ли сделать то, что я хочу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам поможет [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com/) и [MySQL Windows ZIP Archive](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

Comment: С MySQL ясно, спасибо. А без Portable Python можно обойтись?

Comment: а какая с ним у вас проблема?

Comment: да собственно никакой, просто будет ли работать интерпретатор из папки виртуального окружения? Так быстрее гораздо.

Comment: вам не надо использовать виртуальное окружение на флэшке. так вам не нужно переключать версии пайтона.

Answer (score 1):

Из аналогов denwer`a можете попробовать [ampps](http://www.ampps.com/downloads) там вообще всё подряд, включая perl и mongo